# Java: join two lists of Map<String, Object> using Stream

Tags: java

I have two lists of `Map<String, Object>` as shown below:

```
List1=[ {ID=1, actor="A", film="AA"}, 
        {ID=1, actor="B", film="AA"} ]

List2={ [ID = 1, director="C"] } 

Result = { [ID=1, actor="A", film="AA", director="C"], 
           [ID=1, actor="B", film="AA", director="C"] }
```

I want to use the `Stream` class in Java 8 to join these lists.

How do I join the to get the value of Result shown?

Is the `Stream` class in Java 8 fast and stable if `List1` and `List2` are very big?

Comment: Why not simply add all the entries? `list1.addAll(list2);`

Comment: Cannot use addAll method because the result is different with above.

Comment: @nguyenduta What's the key for the `Map`s in the first list. Is it the `actor`? How about the key for the `Map`s in the second list?

Comment: @Cking I want to join these lists on ID

Comment: Yes but what are the keys that you are inserting in the Maps?

Comment: Keys are actor, film (list1) and director (list2)

Answer (score 1):

Ah now I understand what you want :)
I don't know if there is a better way with streams but here is a solution which would work.

```
List<Map<String, String>> resultList = l1.stream()
        .map(m1 -> {
           Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
           map.putAll(m1);
           l2.stream()
               .filter(m2 -> map.get("ID").equals(m2.get("ID")))
               .findFirst()
               .ifPresent(m2 -> map.put("director", m2.get("director")));
           return map;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The above code generates a new List `resultList` and does not modify the other lists `List1` and `List2`. If it does not matter if `List1` gets modified or not you could do it in a cleaner, more readable way.

```
l1.forEach(m1 -> l2.stream()
    .filter(m2 -> m1.get("ID").equals(m2.get("ID")))
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(m2 -> m1.putIfAbsent("director", m2.get("director"))));
```

This way the entries of `list1` get modified. So with the above example `list1` is becomes the `joined list`. But it's actually good practice to have methods without any side effects. So I would not prefer the above example.

I would recommend a method `getJoinedList` which returns a new List and does not modify the other lists. And in this case I would not use `streams` but the old-fashioned for-loop.

```
private static List<Map<String, String>> getJoinedList(
    List<Map<String, String>> l1, List<Map<String, String>> l2) {

    List<Map<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map<String, String> m1 : l1) {
        Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<>();
        newMap.putAll(m1);
        for (Map<String, String> m2 : l2) {
            if (m1.get("ID").equals(m2.get("ID"))) {
                newMap.put("director", m2.get("director"));
                break;
            }
        }
        result.add(newMap);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then you just can call the method like this.

```
List<Map<String, String>> joinedList = getJoinedList(l1, l2);
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it. :)

Answer (score 1):

If performance matters, you should first build an index of directors:

```
Map<Object, Object> directors = list2.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> m.get("ID"), m -> m.get("director")));
```

Then you can merge the directors to the list entries easily:

```
list1.stream().forEach(m -> m.put("director", directors.get(m.get("ID"))));
```

Accesing the director via a `Map` will be faster than searching the director for each list entry.

Comment: The OP seems to have a `List` of `Map` objects.

Comment: @CKing Yes, that's what I do have as well.

Comment: What I am trying to figure out is what exactly does `m.get(“ID")` and `m.get("director")` do. The OP doesn't mention that hey is using the strings "ID" and "director" as keys in the maps.

Comment: @CKing Yes, he did. See the first line. Here's some code: http://pastebin.com/XiDDjQBZ

Comment: I saw your code and that's exactly my question. The OP provided sample input data for `list1` as `[ {ID=1, actor="A", film="AA"}, {ID=1, actor="B", film="AA"} ]`. Pay special attention to the curly braces and the comma. The first map in the list is `{ID=1, actor="A", film="AA"}` followed by a `,`. The second map in the list is `{ID=1, actor="B", film="AA"}`.  But the structure you assume is `{{"ID",1},{"actor","A"},{"film","AA"}} , {{"ID",1},{"actor","B"},{"film","AA"}}`. That's why I asked the OP about the keys in a comment.

Comment: @CKing Just try out the code. When you `System.out.println(list1)`, you'll get `[{actor=A, ID=1, film=AA}, {actor=B, ID=1, film=AA}]`. Same with `list2`.

Comment: Not on a computer right now to try it out. I'll take your word for it. Anyway I did +1 already :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments!

Comment: @steffen I've tried your example. But I have a problem if list2 has two entries as below:
List2={ [ID = 1, director="C"] , [ID=1, director="D"]}

I cannot create indexed list. And the result list which I want as bellow:

Result = { [ID=1, actor="A", film="AA", director="C"], 
           [ID=1, actor="B", film="AA", director="C"],
           [ID=1, actor="A", film="AA", director="D"],
            [ID=1, actor="B", film="AA", director="D"]
}
Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: @Duta Well that's an unusual structure (if you actually can have one ID with two directors, you'd normally collect them to a `Set` instead of creating multiple rows in your result, this is more or less relational database style). I wouldn't use the Java8 Streams API for this. But just for the example, have a look here: http://pastebin.com/2M8GhK3x